# Amount concentration versus number concentration

Tags: concentration, terminology

The [IUPAC Gold Book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/) defines

> **Amount concentration**
>
> Amount of a constituent divided by the volume of the mixture. Also called amount-of-substance concentration, substance concentration (in clinical chemistry) and in older literature molarity. For entities B it is often denoted by B. The common unit is mole per cubic decimetre or mole per litre sometimes denoted by M.

and

> **Number concentration**
>
> Number of entities of a constituent in a mixture divided by the volume of the mixture.

I can't see a distinction between the two terms since it seems to me that "Amount of a constituent" is the same as "Number of entities of a constituent".

Could you please explain the difference between them? Is it a conceptual difference or just a difference in the context in which they are most commonly used?

Answer (score 1):

The "amount" of a substance is the proper term for the "number of moles" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amount_of_substance); [Gold Book](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.A00297)). So, the two quantities are related by a factor of the Avogadro constant, $\pu{6.022\times 10^23 mol-1}$.

If you have $\pu{1 mol}$ of helium in a $\pu{1 m3}$ box, the amount concentration is $\pu{1 mol m-3}$, or $\pu{0.001 mol dm-3}$ if you prefer those units.

The corresponding number concentration is $\pu{6.022\times 10^23 m-3}$.

Comment: Isn't mol just a specific unit for amount? According to the International System of Units, amount of substance is a quantity, while mol is a unit. I think one can use other units for amount if one wishes: tens, thousands, pi, dozens, etc.